# Start next Loop Controller iteration

Tags: loops, groovy, controller, jmeter

I would like to configure something similar to Action to be taken after a Sampler error in Thread Group but at Loop Controller level.

For example, if one Sampler fails, instead of Start Next Thread Loop, I would like to Start Next Loop Controller Loop, I assume this would be achievable using groovy + JMeter properties, but I cannot find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Until Controller from this guy -- http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-until-controller/.
This should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this By using While Loop instead of [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) Use [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

1. Set Action to be taken on sampler error to continue on thread group.
2. Initialize a counter and set its value to 1 using a [beanshell sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) , Keep this sampler  before while loop begins

   Add the following code

   > vars.put("counter","1");

[image]

3. Add A while Loop and keep the set of samplers you want to run in loop.
4. Add the following condition to while loop

> ${__javaScript(parseInt(${counter})<=15,)}

here 15 represents the number of loops (Loop Count)
[image]

5. Add A [beanshell post processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to your first sampler in while loop
   and add the following code (To increment the counter value)

> int counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter")) +1;
>   vars.put("counter",Integer.toString(counter));

[image]

Next samplers in While loop embed with an if condition

> ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}

As shown below You have to do this for each sampler as we may not know where the error occurs.

[image]

In My case i wanted to run the loop 15 times irrespective of errors , You can see its executed 15 times even after getting errors 
[image]

For more information on While controller Follow [this link..](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/jmeter-while-controller/)

Please let me know if it helps ..

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. It looks simple when there are only a few samplers. However, on a complex scenario, do we have to add the If Controller to each sampler?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage).

1. Add If Controller after sampler on failure of which you want to restart the loop
2. Put all requests which are "below" the If Controller to be children of the If Controller
3. Use [`${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) as the If Controller condition

That's it, now If Controller's children will be executed only if previous sampler is successful, otherwise it will be next Loop Controller iteration.

[image: JMeter If Controller Demo]

As you can see from the above demo `Some Other Sampler` was executed only when `Some Sampler` was successful.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. It looks simple when there are only a few samplers. However, on a complex scenario, do we have to add the If Controller to each sampler?